# TextFile to ListView line by line c#

Tags: c#

I have a text file:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

And I have a ListView with only 1 column. I want the ListView show something exactly like the text file. I have used this code:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("cacchuongtrinhchan.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
            lv.Text = line.ToString();
            listView1.Items.Add(lv);
            counter++;
      }
```

But the problem is has an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot add or insert the item '' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it.'

Answer (score 3):

Put `ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();` inside the loop to create new `ListViewItem` for each line.

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("cacchuongtrinhchan.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
    lv.Text = line.ToString();
    listView1.Items.Add(lv);
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting such error Because you are adding same instance of the ListViewItem in each iteration, even though you changed their values. So what you have to do here is, instantiate the `lv` in each iteration with a new instance. The following code will help you to do the same. Take a look into the snippet and let me know if it helps you.

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
     lv.Text = line.ToString();
     listView1.Items.Add(lv);
     counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) and condense everything into a single line? This assumes that `listView1.Items` is a `List<string>`, if it is an array (`string[]`) then remove the `ToList()` call.

*top of code file*

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
```

*body of method*

```
listView1.Items = File.ReadAllLines("cacchuongtrinhchan.txt").ToList();
```